# Keep only rows with duplicated values from a dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm learning spark with scala. I have a dataframe composed by two columns.

```
col1  col2
    a 1 
    b 1 
    b 2 
    c 1 
    c 3 
    b 4 
    d 5
```

I would like to delete all the rows for which the value in col2 is present only once (2, 3, 4 and 5). Basically, what i'm looking for is to do the opposite of dropDuplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the rows to remove using `groupBy` and then do a left anti join to filter dem out:

```
df.join(
  df.groupBy($"col2")
    .agg(count($"col2").as("count"))
    .where($"count"===1),
  Seq("col2"),
  "leftanti"
)
```

Or alternatively using window-functions:

```
df

.withColumn("count",count($"col2").over(Window.partitionBy($"col2")))
.where($"count">1).drop($"count")
```

Comment: I think i'll use the first way, like that i don't need window-functions, maybe i'll look more into it later :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way which involves **Window Functions**. The idea here would be to use a Window ordered by `col2` and check adjacent records - if the previous or next record has same `col2` value - keep the record:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val window = Window.orderBy("col2")

val result = df
  .withColumn("prev", lag($"col2", 1).over(window))
  .withColumn("next", lead($"col2", 1).over(window))
  .where($"prev" === $"col2" or $"next" === $"col2")
  .drop("prev", "next")
```

Comment: Thanks, i just had to import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window to make it works.